# MySQL "extended" vs "show status"

Tags: mysql

When I do `mysqladmin extended` from the command line, my Com_* counters differ completely from doing a `show status` when consoled into MySQL. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html

All was explained there. The session was defaulted to local when consoled, while mysqladmin defaulted to global.